# How to get from left to right-hand side of the equation? $ \sum_{k=0}^{d} \binom{2d+1}{k} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot 2^{2d+1} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I would like to know how the left hand side of the equation is achieved. In particular why the $\frac{1}{2}$ is there. I don't understand how one can get from the left to the right side.

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{d}  \binom{2d+1}{k} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot 2^{2d+1} $$

I have looked at this [wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Series_involving_binomial_coefficients), but it does not help me, since I do not understand why the $\frac{1}{2}$ appears.

Comment: Hint: Look at the "missing half" and use *symmetry*. We have $\binom{2d+1}{k}=\binom{2d+1}{2d+1-k}$.  To see what's happening, use say $d=4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{2d+1}\binom{2d+1}{k}=2^{2d+1}
$$
and 
$$
\binom{2d+1}{k}=\binom{2d+1}{2d+1-k}
$$
transform the sum as follows
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{2d+1}\binom{2d+1}{k}=\sum_{k=0}^{d}\binom{2d+1}{k}+\sum_{k=d+1}^{2d+1}\binom{2d+1}{k}\\
=\sum_{k=0}^{d}\binom{2d+1}{k}+\sum^{2d+1}_{k=d+1}\binom{2d+1}{2d+1-k}\\
=\sum_{k=0}^{d}\binom{2d+1}{k}+\sum_{k=0}^{d}\binom{2d+1}{k}\\
$$
to get the result. In the last step we have used the substitution $k\to2d+1-k$.

Comment: Furthermore, observe $$\sum_{k=0}^{d}\binom{2d+1}{k}1^{2d+1-k}1^{k}$$
and similarly for the second sum.